# Switching HTC ONE M8 into PTP mode

Tags: usb-connection-mode, htc-one

I was wondering is it possible to enable PTP mode on the HTC ONE M8. I want it to work with photo software like iPhoto so I want to enable PTP MODE. I have looked in the setting but can't find anything. I am running Lollipop with HTC Sense.

UPDATE: We still have no solution to this problem, so if anyone knows how to do this please share.

Comment: After researching on Google, I'm afraid there's no PTP mode on HTC One M8, and possibly most of HTC One series, which I also find it strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's support for PTP in HTC One M8.

[I just checked the Device Tree](https://github.com/AOSPA-legacy/android_device_htc_m8/blob/lollipop/rootdir/etc/init.qcom.usb.rc)
There's no usb.config for `ptp` mode.

The only way is to edit the ramdisk and modify init.qcom.usb.rc ..
But I don't think even that'll help, since it requires corresponding modifications to the kernel..

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled dev menu? Settings > about phone > press on build number 7 times. If it's not in that menu on your device, try Settings > storage > more options.

Comment: I have but where is the option to enable PTP?

Comment: This works on my samsung but now I see not on my sony - apologies for that. When searching the sony sites (yes, I know you have an HTC), I see their help desk people saying "I'm afraid i don't know of any way to set PTP-mode in the phone". More digging revealed MSC mode, rather than PTP.  Connecting the phone to my mac in MSC got me an error message that the media was unreadable (meaning the sd card) and did I want to initialize it.

Comment: Found the HTC sync app: http://www.htc.com/us/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx which works on a Mac.

Comment: Yeah I have seen that app but it doesn't fit what I need. As I need the phone to be in PTP to be recognised as a camera or at least so that the photo software treats it as a camera. I thought that all androids could do that. Is there any way I can make it do that. Maybe an app or tweak?

Comment: Ah, again at the mercy of my lack of an HTC.  The sony version of this app lets you dump right into iphoto.  I made the mistaken assumption that the HTC did too as a stock work around for devices without PTP.  Worst case, dropbox or pushbullet could be used.  Use ITTT to send the images automatically to dropbox or pushbullet (or set up dropbox to automatically upload all your photos). Then an automator script to grab them and stuff them into iphoto? Bit Rube Goldbergish but it's a start...

Comment: Hi, I'd suggest to delete this answer since it's wrong (after researching, I think there's no PTP mode for HTC One M8, and possibly HTC One series, which is strange), or otherwise, update your answer based on the comments.